# What are the different methods that i can use to authenticate user from rails server which is a backend of iOS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use rails as backend for ios applications. So far i have been using devise as it looks flexible and comfortable to use with less effort . And i have read about omniauth and that too  looks easy to integrate with devise. My question is, consider my ios app requires authentication and the following are the different methods that i should be able to allow user to do

1. Login using email and password
2. Login using Facebook account
3. Login using Twitter account

Login using email can be handled by the devise itself but how about login using Facebook and twitter? Actually in one of my project i came up with the following approach which has all three of these login process. The ios app authenticates the user from the device(not devise) itself and sends the user information like username, email etc whatever required along with auth type so i save this a separate user with username that is sent and one of the field as password. And the next time he sends me these details i allow him to login to the app. But now i realised this is not the best way to do. I read about FBgraph which can be used to verify the access token validity, so should i get the token from user and then verify it and get the profile information and save it in user model and give them the token.

Also i have another doubt which is, For login using email and password i allow user to login through email and password and then for the each requests the user sends me the username and password. Is this is alright or do i have to create a token in login request and send the token as response and then the user can send the token for all the other request he makes.

Sorry if it is confusing but to tell you shortly i need to know what should i do if i have all these three login process. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

There are couple things to consider when dealing with external applications like on other devices:

1. You should use an API to communicate with your Rails server
2. Your server should send an authentication token after the first user authentication using his email and password. It is not a good idea to send user's email and password for each requests.

#### Devise

Devise is great for authentication both in-app and for remote applications using the `token_authenticatable` hook. This will allow any registered user to have a unique secret token to use in order to be authenticated on your server.

More information [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

#### OAuth2

OAuth2 is becoming the standard way to authenticate on remote services giving the user the possibility to use his Facebook account to login for example.

This would be the easier way to allow your users to authenticate using their Facebook or Twitter account (note that twitter will not give you the user's email address).

Devise can handle OAuth2 clients.

Finally, you could also create your own OAuth consumer to authenticate users using your service. [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) is a great gem to protect your API endpoints and to allow users to use OAuth2.

#### Conclusion

Devise is great for authentication. Using their token module coupled with OAuth2 integration could do the trick in your case.

[Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) is the OmniAuth wiki page from Devise

[Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example) is the Simple Token Authentication wiki page from Devise